# ¿como reinstalar xampp en ubuntu?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, xampp

Perdón por la molestia otra vez ¿saben como puedo aplastar el xampp que actualmente tengo en ubuntu con uno nuevo? Digamos reinstalar pero machacando el que ya tengo ahora. Es que ha ocurrido un error que no puedo corregir por culpa de cambiar los permisos de una carpeta, y como no tengo mucho conocimiento de linux ubuntu prefiero reinstalar. Necesito por favor los comandos, ya perdi todo el dia intentando solucionar lo anterior y nada :(

Comment: Puedes asignarles los permisos con Chmod 777 * y chown root:root *, Elimina la carpeta de xampp por completo /opt/xampp, después puedes reinstalarlo`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes asignarles los permisos con Chmod 777 * y chown root:root *, Elimina la carpeta de xampp por completo /opt/xampp, después puedes reinstalarlo`

Comment: Bienvenido, gracias por contribuir, por favor revisa  [answer]!, 
También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! :D saludos!

obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No hay carpeta xampp, la ruta donde estan mis páginas php es: OPT / LAMPP / HTDOCS / AQUI /MIS PAGINAS... Pero si elimino la carpeta lampp no seguirá instalado el servidor acaso???? Necesito permisos para ver mi base de datos, y crear y eliminar, eso como seria con CHMOD.. Osea que numero tendria que ponerle? Y con que comando elimino carpetas???

Comment: Si quieres darles permisos sería con el CHMOD 777 lectura y escritura en esa carpeta